# Misunderstanding groups in regex, is this possible?

Tags: c#, regex

I think I am misunderstanding how groups work in regular expressions and C#.  But, I am still wondering if what I want is possible.

Let's take the following string

```
:::name(uploadFileName)
```

Which is matched by the expression

```
\A:::[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\)
```

What I want to be able to do is easily extract out something like `property = name` and then `value = uploadFileName`.

I thought that this would happen with groups, where `match.Groups[0].Value` would be `name` and `match.Groups[1].Value` would be `uploadFileName`.  Based on the definition of groups, I thought that would be true:

> Grouping constructs delineate the subexpressions of a regular expression and capture the substrings of an input string.

However, `match.Groups[0].Value` is simply the whole string `:::name(uploadFileName)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0th group is the entire match. Other matches start with 1. However, your regex does not capture anything, as there are no unescaped parentheses. Here is what you could use in case you do not have enclosed parenthetical groups. I'd suggest using named captures here for simplicity:

```
\A:::(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\((?<property>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\)
```

Then, you'll have your results in `match.Groups["name"].Value` (=name) and `match.Groups["property"].Value` (= uploadFileName).

Comment: I prefer your solution, because of the explicit name of the capture group... less error prone, and more readable (when exploiting the results)

Answer (score 4):

The zeroth item is the entire string matched by the regex. The indices after that are the contents of each captured group. So for what you want, you need two capture groups:

```
\A:::([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\)
```

Then `match.Groups[1].Value` will be `name` and `match.Groups[2].Value` will be `uploadFileName`. Note the double parentheses for the second part - the `\(` and `\)` are matching literal parentheses characters, whereas the non-escaped ones are delineating the actual capture group for the regex.

Comment: Ohhh, so parenthesis delineate the capture groups??  That's the key thing I was missing in my understanding.